# Querying synchronised data extention

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, marketing-cloud-connect, activities, data-synchronization

I had a task of getting records from a synchronised data extention and get the opens and clicks from the emails of that DE. The problem is that I cant see those DE in query category .  So, i was wondering if it is possible to query the synchronised data extentions. I cant see the DEs in the query activity .Any help would be appreciated . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. 
Don't get fooled by the UI. Just write the query using the Synched DE's name. (e.g. "SELECT SubscriberKey FROM Account_Salesforce")

In case you are in a child BU, don't forget to add the ENT. prefix, e.g. "SELECT SubscriberKey FROM ENT.Account_Salesforce".

The same works for auto-suppression-configurations by the way:

You can select FROM data extensions not visible on the Automation Studio UI by just specifiying them in the code. You can however not use them as a target, as the target DE cannot be defined in SQL statements, but has to be picked from the UI.

Hope this helped.